# .net - how to implement google maps with klm files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, implementation

I was assigned a task here at work to implement a search in our web application that, when you type (in a single field) the state, city and name of a person (who has a register in the application) the application returns a google map with flags in the places where those people were found.

I know that might be quite a complex functionality to build (for me it is at least). But anyways I need somewhere to get started from.

I decided that it’d be best to learn first how to implement these maps using KLM files. 
I have no idea how to implement this functionality.

I found a few examples of it on google.com  here: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=pt-BR&q=http%3A%2F%2Fkmlscribe.googlepages.com%2FSamplesInMaps.kml&ie=UTF8&ll=36.879621,-53.4375&spn=103.772916,208.476563&z=2&om=1
 but could not find how they are implemented it.

I’m using .net MVC3.

How can I render a map in a view? 
How can I load the map with the data I want?

It would be of great help if you could give me a simple example with some sample data. Just so I have an idea of how to make it work and latter I’ll find out how to make the search filter works and pass the right data to the map.

Thank you all for your help and support.

Regards from Brazil.

Cesar.

Comment: Do you mean [KML (Keyhole Markup Language)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kml) files (rather than KLM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a walkthrough in this website that is pretty good.

I hope you like it.

http://www.gregjopa.com/2011/02/asp-net-mvc-3-with-jquery-mobile-and-google-maps/

Click in demo to check out his demo.

Regards from Brazil.

Cesar.

Answer (score 0):

[KML Explination](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/)

[KML Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)

I must admit, I have never used KML files for Google Maps, only for Google Earth.
It you search here on SO, you will find loads of information on how to set up and perform an address using the Geocoding API.